# How to pass variables of one user to another user in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a user `myuser` and an environment variable `test`

**export var=test**

Saved bashprofile and works fine.

When running a shell script, I like to pass above variable and echo it with different user like below.

**sudo su - anotheruser -c 'echo ${var}'**

I tried this and it did not work. How do I pass the variable in the shell script ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-E` flag of `sudo` to maintain environment variables:

```
sudo -E su anotheruser -c 'echo ${var}'
```

Comment: I tried this solution and still doesn't work.

Comment: @gnanda1 Oops! You have to get rid of the `-` after `su`, then it'll work.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't if the env var is exported